# Bilinear form of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics, bilinear-form

Let V be the vector space Mn×n(R), and let B: V×V→R be the bilinear form B(X, Y) = tr(XY). Calculate the signature of B. Here, tr means the trace of the matrix.
**Edits**

I'm stuck here as I was only able to conclude that this is a symmetric bilinear form (correct me if I'm wrong), then how to proceed after this?
I am having no idea on how to proceed on this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how to proceed on this

Comment: Actually, I am finding difficulty in evaluating the bilinear form.